# Creating Upside Arrow

Tags: swift3, uibezierpath, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to show arrow of my selected page menu. But, the arrow which I draw didn't show as I expected. It needs to be up

Here is my code:

```
class ArrowView : UIView {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

var rect: CGRect!
var arrorBackgroundColor: UIColor?

var midX: CGFloat { return rect.midX }
var midY: CGFloat { return rect.midY }
var maxX: CGFloat { return rect.maxX }
var maxY: CGFloat { return rect.maxY }

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.rect = rect

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    ctx?.beginPath()
    ctx?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

//        Old code which the arrow was down
//        ctx?.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:maxX * 0.2 , y: maxY * 0.2), control: CGPoint(x: maxX * 0.12, y: 0))
//        ctx?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: midX - maxX * 0.05, y: maxY * 0.9))
//        ctx?.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: midX + maxX * 0.05, y: maxY * 0.9), control: CGPoint(x: midX, y: maxY))
//        ctx?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxX * 0.8, y: maxY * 0.2))
//        ctx?.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: maxX, y: 0), control: CGPoint(x: maxX * 0.88, y: 0))

    ctx?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: midX - maxX * 106.5, y: maxY * 65.5))
    ctx?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: maxX * 128.5, y: maxY * 88.5))
    ctx?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 85.5, y: 88.5))
    ctx?.closePath()

    ctx?.setFillColor((arrorBackgroundColor?.cgColor)!)
    ctx?.fillPath();
}

}
```

And here how it goes

[image]

Actually I am trying to customize this library : https://github.com/azurechen/ACTabScrollView

And trying to archive like this : https://puu.sh/viWwc/35a6bddb0d.png

Since I am beginner with `UIBezierPath` , any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the constants in your calls to `addLine(to:)` and I think the implementation of `ArrowView` is unnecessarily weird.

You seem to be confused about `midX`/`maxX`/... (or I'm just too dense to get it right now). The [CGRect documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect) should help.

I think the original author of `ArrowView` (from the github project you linked to) somehow mixed up `bounds` and `frame` when setting the arrow's position. Oh, and he also abused the `rect` parameter in `draw(_:)`, see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw). Specifically (emphasis mine):

> **rect**
>   The portion of the view’s bounds that needs to be updated. The
>   first time your view is drawn, this rectangle is typically the entire
>   visible bounds of your view. *However, during subsequent drawing
>   operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view.*

Also, `ACTabScrollView` seems to work only sometimes. In my shallow experiments, it messed up view positioning most of the time.

Anyways, to implement a simple `UIView` for an upwards pointing arrow, this works:

```
class ArrowView : UIView {
    var arrorBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.red

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        // Sample to really fill the background before drawing the arrow.    
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
        ctx.fill(bounds)

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.maxY))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.minY))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.maxY))
        ctx.closePath()

        ctx.setFillColor(arrorBackgroundColor.cgColor)
        ctx.fillPath()
    }
}
```

The core is using the view's `bounds` to compute the coordinates.

From [the UIView docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview):

> The geometry of a view is defined by its frame, bounds, and center
>   properties. The frame defines the origin and dimensions of the view in
>   the coordinate system of its superview and is commonly used during
>   layout to adjust the size or position of the view. The center property
>   can be used to adjust the position of the view without changing its
>   size. The bounds defines the internal dimensions of the view as it
>   sees them and is used almost exclusively in custom drawing code. The
>   size portion of the frame and bounds rectangles are coupled together
>   so that changing the size of either rectangle updates the size of
>   both.

I think `arrorBackgroundColor` should really be called `arrowColor` (because it is used as the color of the arrow) and you might have another property `arrorBackgroundColor` that really is for the background. I added two lines that fill the background with yellow as an example.

Comment: Thanks for great detail explain. looks like when I tested it, the arrow position direction rise up. But, the view is still down the scroll menu. It will be better if we can move the view up inside the tab menu?don't you think? This is what i am trying to archive : https://puu.sh/viWwc/35a6bddb0d.png. So, if you can help me, it will be awesome.

Comment: For that, you would have to change the code in `ACTabScrollView` that positions the arrow view. I searched for `arrowView.bounds.origin = ` and replaced `bounds` with `frame` and subtracted `arrowView.bounds.height` from `y` so that it reads `arrowView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: (self.bounds.width - arrowView.bounds.width) / 2, y: tabSectionHeight - arrowView.bounds.height)`.

Comment: Oh, and there's two appearances of this. One in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` and one in `setupPages()`.

Comment: When working with drawing rect, your suggestion which fill the color first is really useful. Thanks for that tip. All working fine now. I will try to contribute that library. If you can, you are welcome to contribute as well.